# Reeding BLOB values from Wikipedia dump file

Tags: mysql, dump, wikimedia

I have downloaded a wikipedia dump file and transferred its data to MySQL.

```
SELECT page_id, BINARY CONVERT(page_restrictions USING utf8)  from page
```

I used following query to convert `page_restrictions`  field from blob to string.

I also tried to use following to read `old_text` value but it do not works.

```
SELECT BINARY CONVERT(old_text USING utf8) from text
```

What is wrong with it?

```
mysql> describe text;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| old_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| old_text  | mediumblob       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| old_flags | tinyblob         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `BINARY` in that query. You should just need:

```
SELECT CONVERT(old_text USING utf8) from text
```

That's assuming the blob contains text encoded as utf_8.